# Maximum allowable length of a chain fork

Tags: cardano-node

Where can you check the maximum allowable length of a chain fork for the current era? And past/future eras?

Answer (score 3):

The security window on Cardano is defined as 3k/f, where 10k/f is epoch length. The security window is the farthest one can rollback under normal circumstances. On mainnet this is 36 hours.

Comment: thank you! 

reference found: https://docs.cardano.org/core-concepts/chain-confirmation-versus-transaction-confirmation